# How to remove entries on "Events" tab vSphere Client?

Tags: events, vsphere, esxi

I need to remove some entries on "Events" tab vSphere Client.
I'm using VMWare Esxi 5.5 without VCenter.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible, and mostly not recommended.